# Proof by induction that $ |A \times B| = |A|\cdot|B| $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove by mathematical induction on $ |A| $ that $ |A \times B| = |A|\cdot|B| $, is my proof valid?

The set are finite.

Let $ |B| = m $.

If $ |A| = 0 $, then $ A \times B =  \emptyset, |\emptyset| = 0 = |A|\cdot|B|. $

Assume $ |A| = n $ and $ |A \times B | = nm $. Choose $ x \notin A $. Therefore, for every $ y \in B $, we'll have to consider $ (x, y) $, and there are $ m $ such pairs.
Therefore,$ |A \cup \{x\} \times B| = |A||B| + |B| = |B|(|A| + 1). $

Comment: $|A \cup \{x\} \times B| = |A||B| + |B|$ this is the meat & gravy of your proof, you should elaborate on it more

Answer (score -1):

Hint: It looks like you are trying to do the proof by induction on $|A|$. What you say in the base case is fine, but in the inductive step you are making the wrong assumption: you should assume $|A| = n > 0$ and then prove using the inductive hypothesis that $|A \times B| = |A| \times |B|$. To do that you need to find a set $A'$ with $|A'| = n - 1$ that you can apply the inductive hypothesis to. So you need to pick $x \in A$, and take $A' = A \setminus \{x\}$. Can you take it from there?

[Aside: I prefer to formulate inductive proofs to go from $n$ to $n+1$ in the inductive step rather than from $n-1$ to $n$, but you said assume $|A| = n$ in your proposed proof, so I took it from there.]

Comment: Thanks to whoever for the unexplained downvite. Please grow up and learn that this a forum for people who want to co-operate: if you disagree with something, then, by all means downvote it, but add a comment to explain why. Otherwise, you are contributing nothing, helping no one and discouraging people from trying to help others on MSE.